# Set different page numbering by section when merging PDF pages using iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am merging multiple PDF files using iTextSharp, but I need to re-number the pages by section. For example, I am merging a PDF file that corresponds to the cover of a book, with a PDF file that has the actual content of the book. I want to use I,II,III numbering system for the cover, then use 1,2,3 numbering for the content, so that when the user enters page number 9 in the navigation box, it'll take him/her to the corresponding page in the content.

In Adobe Acrobat, this can be done by selecting the pages and clicking on Number Pages. I would like to do the same but using c# code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short snippet with the relevant lines you'll need:

```
var labels = new PdfPageLabels();
labels.AddPageLabel(sectionPageNumber, pageNumberingStyle, customText, startingNumber);
.
.
.    
pdfWriter.PageLabels = labels;
```

In this snippet:

- `sectionPageNumber` is the page number where the section starts,
- `pageNumberingStyle` is a value such as `PdfPageLabels.UPPERCASE_ROMAN_NUMERALS`, `PdfPageLabels.DECIMAL_ARABIC_NUMERALS`, etc.
- `customText` is any text that needs to go with the page number, and
- `startingNumber` is the page number that this numbering style would start.